# VBA Trying to loop through a column and delete the entire row if they contain a value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not very good at loops.

I'm trying to use VBA to loop through a column to look for any value, and then delete the entire row if it doesn't find anything (It's essentially a way of deleting rows of data that I've marked (or unmarked in this case)).

I've tried various things. My most recent attempt is below but its just deleting every row regardless of whether that cell has a value or not. Any suggestions?

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 1 To 50
If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Else
    i = i + 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You are deleting the selected row not Cells(i, 1) row

Comment: You should iterate backwards or use a new range to be deleted at the end at once, built by using `Union`. This last option will be the fastest one. But the difference would be seen in a very big range...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. When deleting rows in a loop work backwards, if going forward your row number changes as you delete.
2. There is no need to increment variable "i" next i already does this
3. Use the Worksheet object to delete the row rather than Selection

I would rewrite like this:

```
Sub delete()

Dim i As Long
For i = 50 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).EntireRow.delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows(i)` would be enough. I mean, instead of `Rows(i & ":" & i)`...

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation makes perfect sense. I realized i was referencing the wrong column too but this works perfectly. Thank you :)