# Deleting all rows that contain a certain content in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all rows that contain ABC.

I have tried but it only seems to remove half of the rows.

For example if there are 16 rows with ABC in them it will remove 8. If I run again it will remove 4 etc etc

Here's what I tried:

```
Sub DeleteABC()
      
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim xx

With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For xx = 2 To lastRow2
        If .Cells(xx, "C") Like "*ABC*" Then
            .Rows(xx).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
    
End With
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Always go backwards when deleting rows. Try it again but with `For xx = lastRow2 to 2 Step -1` see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63436497/19353309)

Answer (score 2):

Always loop backwards when deleting rows or cells:

```
For xx = lastRow2 To 2 Step -1   ' <-- loop backwards
    If .Cells(xx, "C") Like "*ABC*" Then
        .Rows(xx).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next xx
```

**Edit 1:**
A quicker method of deleting multiple rows will be to save them all first in a `Range` object, and then delte the all of them at once.

***Modified Code***

```
Dim DelRng As Range

For xx = lastRow2 To 2 Step -1   ' <-- loop backwards
    If .Cells(xx, "C") Like "*ABC*" Then
        If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, .Range("C" & xx))
        Else
            Set DelRng = .Range("C" & xx)
        End If
    End If
Next xx

If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete
```